# How do I deal with spaces in a pathname?

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I am trying to use SaveCopyAs where the path name name has 2 spaces in it i.e one of my folders name is "Dropbox (SGPS ShowRig)" and the sub crashes.

BTW: I have successfully tested this with a pathname with NO spaces.
NOTES: I am running this on a Mac using Excel 365.

Here is my code:

```
Sub MySaveCopyAs()

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs FileName:="/Users/phild/Dropbox (SGPS Showrig)/DDocuments/Test.xlsm"

End Sub
```

I have also tried

```
"""/Users/phild/Dropbox (SGPS Showrig)/DDocuments/Test.xlsm"""

'And

"/Users/phild/Dropbox\ (SGPS\ Showrig)/DDocuments/Test.xlsm"
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: *`the sub crashes.`*  Does Excel shut down entirely?  Or just the code exits ungraciously?  No error messages?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:="C:\Users\phild\Dropbox (SGPS Showrig)\Documents\Test.xlsm"?

Go to File Explorer and paste C:\Users\phild\Dropbox (SGPS Showrig)\Documents\ into the path bar to see if it is valid.

Comment: Ah! I didn't notice the "DDocuments" in the original post. But now that you've corrected it, my eyes noticed the difference.